# Call WCF service 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, webforms

I've created an AJAX-enabled WCF Service and I want call it using POST. But the service was 404 not found  and i don't understand why. I saw some examples but can't find why my service is inaccessible. I've already changed my web config but there is no difference. What do I do wrong?

```
namespace ATSite
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SendEmailService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public string HelloWorld(string id)
        {
            return "Hello world " + id;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the service:

```
function helloWorld() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../SendEmailService.svc/HelloWorld",
        data: '{"Id": "2"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            onSuccess(result);
        },
        error: alert('Erro')
    });
}
function onSuccess(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

This is my web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ATSite.SendEmailServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="ATSite.SendEmailService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ATSite.SendEmailServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ATSite.SendEmailService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check ../SendEmailService.svc/HelloWorld path is correct?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you manage to solve this? Moving the service to another application is not an option for me as the functionality depends too much on the project it is in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call it that way. Here is an example on how to consume a wcf service http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service

Comment: But for that I have to create a new project -> WCF service application

Answer (score 0):

The WebInvoke attribute gives you some options:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string MyAwesomeServiceMethod(Decimal value)
    {
        return value.ToString("F2");
    }
```